# how to integrate quickbook desktop application with website

Tags: c#, .net, quickbooks, qbwc

I am new at Quick Book, now I am preparing one Admin panel ( Online website) in which I have to integrate with Quick Book Desktop version.

- I am making this website with .NET ( C#) platform.

There are some posts here, but still the things are not clear to me.

My requirement in short : "We need to send Provider name which is vendor, Date, Invoice number or account ref, Amount paid in the quickbook. Once the amount is paid via quickbook it will appear in the payments section with the mode of payment e.g. Credit card, cash or cheque. I mean it will show the updated status at the website."

1) Which are the way I can communicate/integrate with Desktop QB from my website?
2) What are their processes in detail?
3) Is there anything I need to change?
4) Any Sample code ?

Waiting for your positive responses and help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use QB Web Connector to get data from your desktop company file to your web server.

The Web Connector is explained in more details in the QBWC Programmers Guide included in the QBXML SDK.
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0250_qb/0020_get_set_up/sdk_downloads

There is a Web Connector server example included in the QBXML SDK.

You might also check out Consolibyte's website
http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_web_connector
http://consolibyte.com/quickbooks-open-source/

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, can you please provide me sample for **web server** app which will communicate/talk with WC ?
Also how to handle all this things if data is sync/stored on cloud?

Comment: Also how to call web connector from my web app not from web connector it self??

Answer (score 1):

To integrate your app with QB Desktop, you need to use QBSDK.

Please refer the following link.

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0250_qb
- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0250_qb/0010_get_oriented/0080_quickbooks_web_connector

Thanks

Comment: Still we should provide more details

Comment: what details are u looking for. Have you gone through all the sublinks  from the pages mentioned above ? Specially the sample code link ?
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0250_qb/0050_documentation/sample_code

Comment: okay I have checked above links in detail but still things are not clear to me.
So what I am looking for, 1. I have QB desktop version installed at PC, then I wanna communicate it with website .
So can you please give some explanation with your own words so I can start my implementation for it please?

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, can you please provide me sample for **web server** app which will communicate/talk with WC ?
Also how to handle all this things if data is sync/stored on cloud?