# Quickbooks integration - NOT QBOnline

Tags: quickbooks

I am developing an industry vertical application. Companies are small businesses who will use the application for client management, scheduling, personnel, hiring, billing, etc. The financial records are accurate in the system but most businesses will have their own accounting software, typically Quickbooks for Windows (note: I am NOT interested in any discussion of Quickbooks Online).

I want to enable users to click a button and download their data into QB for Windows, as they do at a bank or credit card account.  I cannot find any documentation on that - it's all on QBOnline. Any guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use QBSDK for this.

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0250_qb
- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0250_qb/0010_get_oriented/0080_quickbooks_web_connector

You can have a look at similar SO threads.

[Integrating with QB Desktop products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22641754/integrating-with-qb-desktop-products)

[how to integrate quickbook desktop application with website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22553205/how-to-integrate-quickbook-desktop-application-with-website)

Thanks